# Logback no ExceptionInInitializerError in file only on console

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, logback, playframework-2.2

I'm using logback 1.7.5 with play framework 2.2.4, during working I'm getting such error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at controllers.db.SyncDBManager.createDeviceCollectionsIfNotExists(SyncDBManager.scala)
    at server.impl.logic.controller.DeviceInitializer.checkAuthenticationResponse(DeviceInitializer.java:226)
    at server.impl.logic.controller.DeviceInitializer.processReceivedFrames(DeviceInitializer.java:117)
    at server.impl.logic.controller.DeviceController.onReceivedPackets(DeviceController.java:77)
    at server.impl.logic.io.DeviceReader.run(DeviceReader.java:130)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
    at controllers.base.MongoSyncHelper$class.$init$(MongoSyncHelper.scala:16)
    at controllers.db.SyncDBManager$.<init>(SyncDBManager.scala:32)
    at controllers.db.SyncDBManager$.<clinit>(SyncDBManager.scala)
    ... 5 more
```

But only on console, how can I catch such exception and write it to file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an ordinary stack trace in a console printed with the sysout. Depending on your design if you want to log an exception with the Play logger you should do it in a catch block with one of logger's methods by passing an exception as one of parameters. For example:

```
try {
  // code
} catch {
  case e: Exception => play.api.Logger.error("An error occurred", e)
}
```

The logger level is up to you. If you don't have a catch block and want to log an unexpected exception that occurs in any place of an application you should log it in the Global object by overriding *onError* method.

```
override def onError(request: RequestHeader, e: Throwable): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  play.api.Logger.error("An error occurred", e)
  super.onError(request, e)
}
```

Remember that *onError* method is called only in the production mode.